# Poor (crackly) midi output in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a question that may or may not have a simple answer. Alright so in Ubuntu 17.10, any application that has midi output sounds crackly. I have tried a native app, LMMS and a web app, Soundtrap, both with the result of crackly audio. Audio from sources like SoundCloud and YouTube is just fine. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What software are you using to synthesize MIDI sounds?

Comment: @CL. I am using ALAS

Comment: ALSA has no built-in MIDI synthesizer.

Comment: @CL. Please forgive me for my ignorance; I am just starting with audio editing, let alone on Linux. I did a bit of research but am a bit confused. Do I need to use Jack or is that totally unrelated?

Comment: LMMS can use either ALSA or Jack. If you are asking, then you did not try to start Jack before starting LMMS. Anyway, what sound card are you using?